# Android 8.1 OS StatusBar

Tags: android, statusbar

I have a new Vivo X21 phone with `Android 8.1.0` OS. I use the follow code.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

This hides the `status-bar`, but `ContentView` is not full screen and `statu-bar` is Black. 
This make my App ugly. This works with `Android 7` and lower.

But in the android guide doc it says that `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` will set full screen and hide the `status-bar`. Anyone who know why and what can I do to hide the `statu-bar`..?

Thanks!!

Comment: that is probably device-specific issue, not Andorid version-specific